# I can't understand why my foreach loop won't load all members

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach

```
namespace FitnessClub
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            Member[] clubMembers = new Member[5];

      
            clubMembers[0] = new NormalMember("Special Rate", "James", 1, 2010);
            clubMembers[1] = new NormalMember("Normal Rate", "Andy", 2, 2011);
            clubMembers[2] = new NormalMember("Normal Rate", "Bill", 3, 2011);
            clubMembers[3] = new VIPMember("Carol", 4, 2012);
            clubMembers[4] = new VIPMember("Evelyn", 5, 2012);

            foreach (Member m in clubMembers)
            {
                m.CalculateAnnualFee();
                Console.WriteLine(m.ToString());
                Console.Read();

            }


        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to learn why my code, when running, only loads James?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "loads"?  Are you saying that when you debug this, you observe that the loop only iterates once?  Can you provide the class definitions as well to replicate the problem?

Comment: You haven't shown us the code for `CalculateAnnualFee()` or `ToString()`.  Show us the Member class.

Comment: `Console.Read()` blocks until the user presses Enter.  So, after displaying the string representation of James' `Member` instance, it will wait for that.

Comment: The code will stop at `Console.Read()` because it's reading from the console. See [`Console.Read`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: Thank you, BACON/Heretic Monkey. That now makes sense. Very constructive :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is waiting for an input, as per your Console.Read() you have at the end of the loop.